# AWS Amplify Auth with Google Login not returning configured scopes

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, federated-identity

I'm creating a simple app with React, AWS Amplify, and Amplify Auth [Cognito] Federated Login with Google.

I have followed the basic add auth instructions from the Amplify Getting started. I successfully get a SignIn/SignUp control rendered.

I'm using the Amplify React UI component [https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator]

```js
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

It works as I per the Getting Started guide, but I'm missing scopes?

[Inspector showing CognitoUser Object Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe0Qq.png)

The user object [CognitoUser] only has sub in the attributes. I would have expected a lot more. Given the config aws-exports.js looks like this.

```json
"oauth": {
        "domain": "stb05h46geob-staging.auth.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com",
        "scope": [
            "phone",
            "email",
            "openid",
            "profile",
            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
        ],
        "redirectSignIn": "http://localhost:3000",
        "redirectSignOut": "http://localhost:3000",
        "responseType": "code"
    },
```

Here is the payload of the JWT

```
{
  "sub": "696ccdef-1e71-4e1b-b629-xxxxxxxxx",
  "cognito:groups": [
    "eu-west-2_xxxxxx_Google"
  ],
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx",
  "version": 2,
  "client_id": "xxxxx",
  "origin_jti": "fb7ea06f-xxxx-49ac-a1e6-xxxxxxx",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin phone openid profile email",
  "auth_time": 1647160588,
  "exp": 1647164188,
  "iat": 1647160588,
  "jti": "d0530efd-xxxx-4dc7-ab36-xxxxxxx",
  "username": "google_10614631950xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I suspect my lack of OAuth2 flow understanding is hindering this...

Is there something anyone can suggest I try to get email [or other scopes] returned after signing in?